# SwiftUI Text Editor Crash with Apple Pencil Long Press

Tags: swiftui, crash, swiftui-texteditor

Using Apple Pencil with SwiftUI text editor, when the user presses and holds in the middle of text already in the editor box a crash occurs.  This is very reproducible even on this minimal example.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var text: String = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $text)
                .background(Color.init(red: 242, green: 242, blue: 242))
                .border(.black)
                .frame(height: 200)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

When tapping and holding somewhere in the middle of the sentence, for example on the word "jumps" the app crashes with an exception reading: Thread 1: "NSTextContentStorage: Inconsistent element cache state. Elements for range {0, 43} are already cached while trying to insert"

The stack trace:
[image: stack trace]

I have attempted to use the approach discussed in this [post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/724216) to make the underlying UITextView use TextKit 1, but could find no UITextView in the underlying UIView hierarchy. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We experienced this same crash as of iOS 16 and still in iOS 16.3.

Long pressing an Apple Pencil inside a UITextView (instantiated in code) causes Scribble to *sometimes* insert a long wrapped--almost 2 lines--of blanks, after which there is a short delay and crash with exception "...Inconsistent element cache state...".

This crash can be prevented by changing the layout manager of the UITextView from TextKit 2 (now the iOS 16 default) to TextKit 1, which is done strangely enough by simply accessing the UITextView.layoutManager property as described in Apple's source code:

```
// To ensure compatibility with older code, accessing the .layoutManager 
// of a UITextView - or its .textContainer's .layoutManager - will cause 
// a UITextView that's using TextKit 2 to 'fall back' to TextKit 1, and 
// return a newly created NSLayoutManager. After this happens, 
// .textLayoutManager will return nil - and _any TextKit 2 objects you 
// may have cached will cease functioning_. Be careful about this if you 
// are intending to be using TextKit 2!
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSLayoutManager *layoutManager API_AVAILABLE(ios(7.0));
```

NOTE that this does stop the strange insertion of the extra long blank lines, but instead just makes those blanks vanish when the pencil touches down again.

Comment: Agreed to all that you have said and I see that you have posted this same answer in the post linked in the question.  I have not, however, been able to figure out how to change the UITextView layout manager for SwiftUI views. As I mentioned at the end of my post, I am unable to access any UITextView in the view hierarchy when iterating through the views.  Do you have any guidance for performing this action for SwiftUI?

Comment: Unfortunately the code that has our problem is not using SwiftUI. I do have another project in SwiftUI that will need to support Apple Pencil eventually, but you are already further along this path than me--so I look forward to what you discover.